# Cannot Call Module Library BroadCast Receiver in Project

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-library

I have Created Module Library in My Project for Call Install_Refferer, But When i Call it in My Project That time Broadcast Class is not Called.
here is my Module Library Receiver Class :

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("ABC@@", "Hello");
}
```

i have Register Receiver in App Manifest

```
 <receiver
        android:name="abc.com.installtrack.InstallTrack.InstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver,InnerclassSeparator">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```